# Week number calculation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first question on Stack.

I am working on a booking site that relies heavily on searching and finding full weeks of accommodation. Most user searches will be on weeknumber of the year, eg. week 27 for the first week of july.

It is important that the user does not need to fill in year when searching for accommodation, and so the only thing we will get from the user is the weeknumber.

How can I get the year from the week given by the user considering that it always has to be the next upcoming occurrence of that week number?

(There is a gotcha in this. I could get the upcoming week 27 by doing something like this:

```
def week
  week = 27
  Date.commercial(Date.current.year + 1, week, 1) # gives the first day of the week
end
```

But that would only be right until the 1 of January, after that it would be looking for week 27 of 2015.)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not an answer, but related: In your forms, you can use `week_field` [Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-week_field) and `week_field_tag` helpers for nice inputs. Just learned about them. Maybe with such a helper in your search form, you need not transform "27" into a week at all.

Comment: Another note as I just stumbled across some week-picker helpers: [week-picker](https://github.com/morshedalam/week-picker) and [kalendae](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the current calendar week with `Date.current.cweek` [(Reference)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cweek) with your number.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext' # Already included in Rails

def calendar_week(week)
  now = Date.current
  year = now.cweek < week ? now.year : now.year + 1
  Date.commercial(year, week, 1)
end

p calendar_week(49)
# => Mon, 02 Dec 2013

p calendar_week(1)
# => Mon, 30 Dec 2013 # don't know if that's the way calendar weeks are counted

p calendar_week(27)
# => Mon, 30 Jun 2014
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, exactly what I was looking for. Heads up for the tip on week fields too.